# Just installed Ubuntu on my PC in a new partition. Nothing after

Tags: grub2

My PC just boots up into Windows. How can I select the Ubuntu partition? It doesn't show any GRUB menu whatsoever.

Comment: some laptops have hard-coded UEFI boots - is there a FN9, F12 or someother Fn number to display your boot menu?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you chose to restart now and your computer booted straight into Windows without giving the option for Ubuntu.

Log into Windows and click the power icon next to your username in the top right corner.

Hold down the shift key and select to restart your computer. Keep the shift key held down until your computer reboots.

At the point of the UEFI settings appearing choose to boot from USB again.

You will now be booted back into the live session of Ubuntu.

Now open a terminal: Ctl + Alt + T

Update your grub by typing 'sudo update-grub'

This will detect all boot options and update them. You may now restart your computer. 'sudo reboot'

If the comupter still loads into Windows continue to next steps:

Restart the computer again by selecting restart and holding the shift key to login to ubuntu live cd.

Now open up a terminal: Ctl + Alt + T

Type the following command:

'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair'

A boot repair screen will appear after install completes.

Click -》 "Recommended repair".

You may receive a message stating "EFI is detected". This is just an informational message as far as I am concerned because it is perfectly fine to install Ubuntu with EFI turned on.

After clicking "OK" to the EFI detected message the utility performed a few tasks and then asked me to select some text and run it in a terminal window.

If you are asked to do this open a new terminal window (press the "super" key, enter "term" into the Dash and click on the icon that appears).

Copy the text from the boot repair window by selecting it with the mouse. Press CTRL and C and then right click in the terminal window and select paste.

Make sure all the commands have run correctly. You may need to press return to get the last command to run.

Now click on the "Forward" button within the boot repair application. You may be asked to copy and paste more text.

Repeat the process of selecting all the text, press CTRL and C and then right click in the terminal window and select paste.

Make sure the commands run.

Keep following through on the process until the boot repair finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Disable hibernation mode and fast startup in Windows.
Open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
powercfg /h off
```

Open the legacy version of the **Windows Control Panel** - not the modern one.
Select **Power Settings** - enable **show hidden settings** - **uncheck fast startup**.

After having finished - **shutdown the computer completely** - do NOT reboot.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.